# How to locate Flutter and Dart on Visual Code?

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

I did not find an answer to my problem on the Web.

---

I am trying to install flutter. So, as explained in https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/linux (I am using Ubuntu, Linux), I installed Flutter with `snap`, then `Android Studio` and `Visual Code`.

Here is the output of `flutter doctor`:

```
$ flutter doctor
> Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
> [✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 1.20.2, on Linux, locale en_US.UTF-8)
>  
> [✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.2)
> [!] Android Studio (version 4.0)
>     ✗ Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
>     ✗ Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
> [!] Connected device
>     ! No devices available

! Doctor found issues in 2 categories.
```

So, it is clear that flutter has correctly been installed (I do not care of Android dependency, I want to work on Visual Code).

However, after having following the steps on https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/editor?tab=vscode I have a problem.

I have correctly installed the Flutter extensions, but when I ran `Flutter: Run Flutter Doctor` I got the following outputs log:

```
[11:32:22 PM] [General] [Info] Environment PATH:
[11:32:22 PM] [General] [Info]     /home/adrien/.local/bin
[11:32:22 PM] [General] [Info]     /usr/local/bin
[11:32:22 PM] [General] [Info]     ...
[11:32:22 PM] [General] [Info]     /snap/bin/flutter/bin
[11:32:22 PM] [General] [Info] Searching for flutter
[11:32:22 PM] [General] [Info]     Looking for flutter in:
[11:32:22 PM] [General] [Info]         /home/adrien/.local/bin
[11:32:22 PM] [General] [Info]         /usr/local/bin
[11:32:22 PM] [General] [Info]         ...
[11:32:22 PM] [General] [Info]         .../bin
[11:32:22 PM] [General] [Info]         /snap/bin/flutter/bin
[11:32:22 PM] [General] [Info]     Found at:
[11:32:22 PM] [General] [Info]     Candidate paths to be post-filtered:
[11:32:22 PM] [General] [Info]     Returning SDK path undefined for flutter
[11:32:22 PM] [General] [Info] Searching for dart
[11:32:22 PM] [General] [Info]     Looking for dart in:
[11:32:22 PM] [General] [Info]         /home/adrien/.local/bin
[11:32:22 PM] [General] [Info]         /usr/local/bin
[11:32:22 PM] [General] [Info]         ...
[11:32:22 PM] [General] [Info]         .../bin
[11:32:22 PM] [General] [Info]         /snap/bin/flutter/bin
[11:32:22 PM] [General] [Info]     Found at:
[11:32:22 PM] [General] [Info]     Candidate paths to be post-filtered:
[11:32:22 PM] [General] [Info]     Returning SDK path undefined for dart
```

Visual Code does not find Flutter (neither Dart). I tried to restart Visual Code but nothing changed.

By the way, there is a point I do not understand. Why isn't `dart` on my computer? Here the output of two commands to see it:

```
$ which flutter
> /snap/bin/flutter
$ which dart
>
```

(dart returns nothing)

---

I am sure the problem is stupid, but I do not know how to solve it! I hope one of you could help me.

Thank you

Comment: If you open a new terminal inside vs code and run flutter doctor does it work?

Comment: If I do so, it outputs the same as in a classical terminal (2 issues related to Android Studio)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the flutter snap folder and see if you actually have /snap/bin/flutter/bin.
It could be that it is installed in $HOME/snap/flutter/common/flutter/bin.

Once located the correct folder, add it to the PATH in the .profile or .bashrc file:
For Flutter: $HOME/snap/flutter/common/flutter/bin
For Dart: $HOME/snap/flutter/common/flutter/bin/cache/dart-sdk/bin

Comment: Indeed, I found Flutter inside $HOME! How this is possible? `Which` wasn't telling me that it was located in `/snap/bin/flutter`? Moreover, there is effectively something at `/snap/bin/flutter` (not a folder according to the terminal), but what does it correspond to? Thank you

Comment: I edited the PATH inside Visual Code Terminal and now all works! However, I have to edit PATH every time I launch the application (or via the terminal only). How can I keep the change constant in PATH?

Comment: Does your environmental variable $PATH include /snap/bin/flutter, you can check with the terminal? To add to the PATH permanently open the .profile file in $HOME and at teh very end where it is # set PATH so it includes user's private bin directories - add to the path like: PATH="$HOME/snap/flutter/common/flutter/bin/cache/dart-sdk/bin:$PATH". After that logout and login.

Comment: Yes, `snap/bin/flutter` is included in $PATH. Thank you, all works!

Answer (score 1):

Did you update the path? Try running VSCode as sudo

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

https://www.techomoro.com/how-to-install-and-setup-flutter-on-ubuntu-18-04-1-lts-bionic-beaver/

if you want to be permentaly add flutter path, follow step 3.3 , 5
instead of showed path in this blog add your flutter path

works with all ubuntu,linux versions.this worked for me if not let me know

Answer (score 0):

It's not the OP question but might help someone who reaches this with problems in Dart but not in Flutter.

I was using the Dart bin included with Flutter for all my Dart projects until the day I had to use `dart2js` in a project. VS Code was complaining about not founding Dart SDK but it was indeed found in Flutter SDK.

The solution was to install Dart from the [get Dart website](https://dart.dev/get-dart) and update the PATH for dart-SDK, which now includes `dart2js`.

In Flutter projects I still use the Flutter the Dart SDK.